# Repeat an user control in user interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I am using ASP.NET Web Forms and i created a custom .ascx user control which represents a Car having properties like Type, Picture and Color.

Now i try to add on user interface this custom control in a repetitive way. Lets say if i have in database 5 cars, then 5 user controls will be render on UI preferable inside an asp control.

I was looking for such a control, studying the grid view, and repeater but they seems to have as data source only lists of objects which are build from "primitive" types not objects like a list of my custom ascx control.

My question is if i can somehow to render those user controls inside a repetitive cycle inside an asp or html control which gives the option to format it (supports css) ? (and  if so please provide me an example)

Comment: Why would you want to render usercontroll it seems like you are passing actual values in the user control items instead you can just generate this items.

Comment: Having an user control i can reuse the same user interface format in multiple places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `ListView` with your user control inside of it, and then bind a `List<CarObject>` to that `ListView`

```
<asp:ListView ID="listView1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <myUC:MyUserControl ID="myUserControl" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Bind a list of your object, such as  `List<Car>`, to that list view, `listView1.DataSource = myListOfCars;`. Then in a `ItemDataBound` event bind your object to your user control.

You could also, alternatively, place the markup from your user control inside of the `ListView`, and then bind the information inside of an `ItemDataBound` event and sidestep the whole user control issue altogether. This still allows you to reuse the markup.